# How could I get songs of a specific album filtered by Category using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my Song model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const songSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  singer: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  categoryId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  },

  albumId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Album",
  },
  __v: { type: Number, select: false },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Song", songSchema);
```

As the title said, I wish to get back all songs of a specific album filtered by category. I am still new to mongodb and would like to understand how could I use aggregate to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for mongoose?

Comment: I have tried to, but I found it very broad and did not find an example of how to do something like it. I just need one clear example and I'll be able to handle all likewise queries myself.

Answer (score 0):

Models come with a [`find` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) that allows you to filter by column. Their documentation shows the following examples:

```js
// find all documents
await MyModel.find({});

// find all documents named john and at least 18
await MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 } }).exec();

// executes, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});

// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();

// passing options
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }).exec();
```

Comment: How could I filter by a specific field?

Comment: For example, I would like to get back all students and filter them by categoryOfStudent (freshmen, graduate.....), assuming that 'categoryOfStudent' is a field in the Student model.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation or at least the example code? It basically tells you exactly what you need, i.e. `Student.find({ categoryOfStudent: 'whatever' })`.

Comment: What I want back is an array containing each categoryOfStudent and the students associated with that specific category. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Read the documentation. I'm sure there's something about grouping or aggregation in there. Otherwise Google it, I'm 100% sure there'll be results, since that's quite a common need.